# After uploading to apple Error: ITMS-90284: Invalid Code Signing

Tags: macos

After uploading our app for shipping to the Mac App Store, we always receive a messange from apple with this issue, but i cant find a good answer how to solve it: "ITMS-90284: Invalid Code Signing - The executable 'com.xy.xy.pkg/Payload/xy.app/Contents/MacOS/xy' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."

I changed and renewed the certs but no chance to solve it.
Im using latest catalina macOS. Not using Xcode for code signing, using terminal as this is a unreal game: codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:" --entitlements entitlements.plist xy.app/ and for packaging: productbuild --component xy.app/ /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:" xy.pkg

thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0):

the explantion to this error: My embedded.provisionprofile cert file was not for "3rd Party Mac Developer".

For all those with a similar problem or error Message, its quite simple: just preview the embedded.provisionprofile if the "3rd Party Mac Developer" is listed below - if not, it will throw out this error.
You need to go to "profiles" + (new Profile) and select "Distribution/Mac App Store". Here the right "3rd Party Mac Dev" Cert with your Bundle id for the app will be generated.